# Set default appliation to open files

Tags: default, extension

I have files with the extension `.case` that I want to open with the software [paraview](https://paraview.org). I can open such a file either using the terminal (`paraview file.case`) or opening it directly from the software.

But when I double-click on the file in the terminal, it says that there is no application installed to open such a file, and in the menu *Open with another application*, Paraview doesn't appear in the list (while it appears in the list of application).

Is there a way to tell ubuntu that I want all `case` files to be open with `/usr/bin/paraview` ? I'm using ubuntu `20.04`.

I found some posts dealing with this problem, but I didn't manage to solve mine with them...

Comment: If there is no `.desktop` file for the `paraview` software, you can create one and put it under your `~/.local/share/applications/` directory. After that, you should be able to "associate" the `.case` extension with this "application" as you tried already.

Answer (score 1):

One possible problem why this is happening is because the .desktop file doesn't accept files.

- Locate the paraview.desktop file (it could be in a number of locations. Start looking in `/usr/share/applications/` or `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/`)
- Open it with a text editor. In the `Exec` line there should be a `%U` at the end.
- If not, make a copy of the file in `~/local/share/applications/`
- Modify the file by adding the `%U` at the end of the Exec line like this: `Exec=paraview %U` line.
- Make the file executable.
- Log out and in again.
- Try opening a .case file with the right-click Open with command.
- If successful, right-click the file again, choose Properties followed by open with.

Comment: I made what you said, but this doesn't work : I have the same behavior as earlier. I tried to add the `%U` or to give the full path to paraview (as explained on [this page](https://www.maketecheasier.com/create-desktop-file-linux/))

Comment: Are you sure you made the .desktop file executable?

Comment: Yes : I tried `chmod u+x paraview.desktop` and also `chmod +x paraview.desktop`.
When I try to open a `.case` file by double-clicking on it, the error message is « no application is installed for files " fichier IFF " [...]» (nb : as my system language is French, I translated for this post only what is outside the quotes in the message)

Comment: What happens if you run `paraview /path/to/.case file` in a terminal?

Comment: it works well : paraview opens it

Comment: Did you leave a space before the `%U`? Also make sure you're launching the modified .desktop file and not the original one. To be sure you're launching the correct one, you could modify the `Name=` field slightly to distinguish between the two .desktop files.